# How to validate form with on span click

Tags: jquery, validation, jquery-validate

**HTML**

```
<form action="#" id="MyForm" name="MyForm">
<table id="tblData">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <label >
                A</label>
            <input id="A" name="A" type="text" value="" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <span id="submitButton">Next</span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</form>
```

**JQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#submitButton').validate(
    {
        rules: {
            A:
            {
                required: false,
                range: [1, 100]
            }
        },
        messages: {
            A: {
                range: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter a valid range.")
            }
        }
    });
});
```

**Script Files**

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.9.1.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.0/jquery.min.js" ></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.js"
    ></script>
```

**Question**

If you pay attention to the HTML, we have span. I want to Validate the form on clicking this span instead of Input Button. Problem is, validation is not occuring. How can i do that?

### **[JSFiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/N8H74/)**

Comment: You're including jquery twice!!! :O

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#submitButton").click(function(){
        $('#MyForm').submit();
    });

    $('#MyForm').validate({
        rules: {
            A: {
                required: true,// here set false if not require as you did it in your question
                range: [1, 100]
            }
        },
        messages: {
            A: {
                range: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter a valid range.")
            }
        }
    });

});
```

see **[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/riturajratan/N8H74/12/)**  and reference [validate](http://jqueryvalidation.org/)

Answer (score -1):

You'll need to upgrade your jquery

Taken from http://jqueryvalidation.org/:

> Required
>
> jQuery, tested with 1.6.4, 1.7.2, 1.8.3, 1.9.0

So maybe use this:

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score -1):

I updated the fiddle and you can see the answer now at [Link](http://jsfiddle.net/ankur20us/N8H74/9/)

I changed the code to this :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('#submitButton').click(function () {


    $("#MyForm").validate({
        rules: {
            A: {
                required: false,
                range: [1, 100]
            }
        },
        messages: {
            A: {
                range: jQuery.validator.format("Please enter a valid range.")
            }
        }
    });
  });

});
```

Comment: It is merely showing the message box and not validating the form. :)

Comment: Just see the link I changed it there